# how to update data lake table schema to match data source using synapse analytics

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-synapse-analytics

So there's a data synapse link created to ingest data from ms dynamics to dataverse (data lake). However, the schema in data verse didn't have the pkeys of the data source and some data types are inconsistent. Now I'm trying to figure out the best approach on synching the schema of the two including the keys and the indexes if possible. Basically just adding the keys to the data lake database and update some data types.

Can I directly do this update in the lake database using Synapse Analytics Live? Will the update affect the old data?

Please note that another person set this all up and I'm trying to fix it.

I am not sure if this can also be done using Power Apps. I currently do not have admin access to the database and there is no dev environment yet for me to play it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you make changes directly in storage, the definitions of your lake databases will become out of sync.

Know More about [Lake database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/database-designer/concepts-lake-database)

- To add keys to the data lake database and update data types.

You can create a **Custom Table**
[image]

**Columns and Datatypes:**
[image]

**Establish Relationships:**
[image]

**Map Data:**

- Map data Allows us to map the table that got selected. And by taking some data I have already got in Lake.

Know more abot [Map Data in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/database-designer/overview-map-data)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Once the file is loaded you will have to create a new mapping name and it will load a designer for the Column mapping with.

**Create Pipeline:**
[image]

Create pipeline will create a folder and creates 2 Objects in it.
One is the Parent Pipeline for the whole data mapping.
And Parent Pipeline kicking off the child pipeline for the mapping dataflow.

In the dataflow the data is pushed to sink in the lake database.

Comment: @MauMau revert me for any blocker.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This worked for me - I created the custom table in another Lake Database so I can use the same table schema and name. Now we will need to reroute our reports to use this as the data source.

Comment: Hey, just a followup question, so I was able to follow through everything and it worked. But this time I wanted to add my teammate to be able to edit the lake database I created. 
I tried the steps stated in here including the giving of access to the user, but to no avail. The "Open" in the lake database won't just show up.
These are the steps I followed in giving the access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/shared-databases-access-control